# How to covert the follow code to lambda expression?

Tags: java, lambda, syntax, java-8

I'm learning lambda, and I know the 3 steps rule which is:

1. Removing the method name
2. Removing the parameter types
3. Removing the return statement

```
MyInterface myInterface = new MyInterface() 
{
    @Override
    public void printMe(String message) {
        System.out.println(message);
    }
};
```

Is the answer

```
MyInterface myInterface = new MyInterface(message -> message);
```

Or

```
MyInterface myInterface = message -> System.out.println(message);
```

Or I maybe all wrong...?

Comment: For these type of questions you can answer them yourself by simply running it on your favourite IDE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second option is correct. But note you could clean the code up even further by using method references:

```
MyInterface myInterface = System.out::println;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
MyInterface myInterface = new MyInterface(message -> message);
```

The above line of code gives you compilation error.Howerver your last option is correct.

You can use `method reference` or write your own `lambda` expression

```
MyInterface myInterface = System.out::println; // using method reference
```

or

```
MyInterface myInterface = message-> System.out.println(message);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll add an important points to complete others answers :

1. Where can you use lambdas ?

> You can use a lambda expression in the context of a functional
>   interface (In a nutshell, a functional interface is an interface that
>   specifies exactly one abstract method)

So your interface **`MyInterface`** should be a functional interface.

2. The function descriptor.

> The abstract method in your functional interface is called
>   **`function descriptor`**, so in order to assign a lambda expression to a
>   Functional interface, the lambda should have the same signature as the
>   abstract method

For example your interface `MyInterface` receives only lambdas that takes a string parameter and doesn't return any thing ( void ).

---

**Extras**

The **`java.util.function`** package contains many Functional interfaces that can help you working and using lambdas and so we can say that your interface is of type Consumer, which is a functional interface that takes an object in input and (consume it) return void, see [Package java.util.function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html)